# Securing Jersey 2 Rest API

Tags: java, security, tomcat, jersey-2.0, saas

I'm building a webcrawler (similar to http://diffbot.com | SAAS) with Jersey 2. 
Other developers should be able to use this API (make a request -> get a JSON response) in a secure way.

Here is the flow:

A users goes to the applications website (register/login).

After the login/registration he should see a panel with API_KEY and API_SECRET.

He can now use this API_SECRET to access the API and therefore the crawler.

Is Ouath suitable for that? Are there better/simpler solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to offer your users the possibility to register applications that can use your API.

I would say for your use case you don't necessarily need OAuth. A simple authentication method like basic authentication (with SSL) would also be sufficient.

As [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) put it:

> [OAuth] specifies a process for resource owners to authorize third-party access to their server resources without sharing their credentials.

What you could use OAuth for: To give your users access to your resources (your API), but you want to let them use an existing account for that (say for example their Github account). This way a user does not need an account with your site, but he can authorize his application against your API using Github's authorization facilities.

If you don't mind spending a few hours on learning [a bit](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2) about OAuth, it will offer you more flexibility.